# Spark XML API - Text between tags

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-xml

Using Spark XML I'm trying to get to the text that appears between 2 elements within a root element. For example:

```
<a>
  <b>x</b> cannot be seen <b>y</b> neither
</a>
```

I would like to get to the text between b elements (text *cannot be seen*  and text *neither*)

Below is the code that I have tried

```
val dfTagA = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","tagA").load("in/test.xml") 
dfTagA.printSchema() 
dfTagA.show(false)
```

Any ideas how to get this through a custom schema using Spark XML libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code and the output you get. You could use [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) guidelines.

Comment: Hi Vladislav, thanks! Please, see below the code.

Comment: The XML is the following text.xml:

  <tagA>
    <tagB>Inside Tag B 1</tagB>
    Text between tag Bs
    <tagB>Inside Tag B 2</tagB>
  </tagA>

Comment: The Scala code using Spark XML libraries is the following (Test.scala):

val dfTagA = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag","tagA")
  .load("in/test.xml")

dfTagA.printSchema()

dfTagA.show(false)

Comment: The output of this code is the following (the schema is obtained automatically by Spark XML library):

root
 |-- tagB: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+--------------------------------+
|tagB                            |
+--------------------------------+
|[Inside Tag B 1, Inside Tag B 2]|
+--------------------------------+
What I would like to get somehow is the text that is between the tagB's (text is Text between tag Bs). I've tried using custom schemas and using the methods Spark XML provides, but I'm not able at all.

Thanks in advance